# Any snmp manager with buzzer on alarm?

Tags: snmp, snmp-trap

Is there any SNMP manager or trap manger with buzzer notifications on PC normal speaker? With alarms that can be defined to activate this buzzer upon specific traps.

Comment: This doesn't look specific enough to be a programming question. If you have a problem implementing such a trap manager, please post your code and ask a more specific question. If you're looking for recommendations for a third-party software to install, this is not the right web site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NetDecision TrapVision](http://www.netmechanica.com/products/?prod_id=1003) for that. It comes with built-in trap handler that supports audible alarms.

[image]
[image]